# File name along side count the number elements divided per 2

Tags: linux, shell, grep, tabular

I have several files I want to get the number of a particular element. But I then want to divide that count per 2.

The final final I wish to get is a table. The first column would be file name and the second the elements count divided per 2.

I have tried this

```
for i in *; do echo $i && grep -c elements $i ; done
```

My output give

> file1
>
> count
>
> file2
>
> count

But I would like to get

> file 1    count/2
>
> file 2    count/2

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in *; do echo -e "$i" '\t'  $(($(grep -c elements $i) /2)) ; done
```

Comment: Don't you need to add `|bc`, in order to execute the calculation? (`echo $(6/2)` gives an error message, while `echo 6/2 | bc` gives 3)

Comment: @Dominique it's using double bracket. Try `echo $((1+1))` and see

Answer (score 0):

With GNU awk for ENDFILE all you need is one call to one tool:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '/elements/{++c} ENDFILE{print FILENAME, c/2; c=0}' *
```

That'll be orders of magnitude faster than a shell loop calling multiple tools once per file.